# How to modify this read more js

Tags: javascript, php

http://jsfiddle.net/raininglemons/wutu9k7k/

```
(function () {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        // Find .readmore parent
        var parent = buttons[i].parentElement;
        while (parent !== null && !parent.className.match("readmore"))
            parent = parent.parentElement;

        // Reached top of dom tree and didn't find .readmore element
        if (parent === null)
            continue;

        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            // Cancel default button behaviour
            event.preventDefault();

            // Add .showall class to parent
            parent.className = parent.className + " showall";
        });
    }
})();
```

This only shows all content and button disappears.I wish too hide content by pressing same button just to back to original state.

Comment: I have updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wutu9k7k/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Based on **@cmorrissey** suggestion i've changed the condition to be more general in case of several classes.

---

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wutu9k7k/7/)**.

Your code work fine after two changes.

**First :** Remove following style that hide the button after click :

```
/* hide button when revealing all */
.readmore.showall button {
   display: none;
}
```

**Second :** Add condition in your `click` event to check in the `show_all` class is already in parent `div` or not :

```
buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    // Cancel default button behaviour
    event.preventDefault();

    // Add .showall class to parent
    if(!parent.className.match("showall")){
        parent.className = parent.className + " showall";
        this.innerText = "Read less"; //Optionally if you want to change 
    } else {
        parent.className = parent.className.replace("showall", "");
        this.innerText = "Read more"; //Optionally if you want to change 
    }
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this works!
But read less label remains after reverting to read more.

Comment: I've changed read less in else and it now works!
Thanks really helps this.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki this will not work properly if you add more classes on the main element ie `class="readmore customClass"` , see my answer posted in the comments which will work correctly no matter what by using `match` and `replace`

Comment: @creeds check the update please.

Comment: Thanks again :)
I have another question: Can sliding up and down to be more slowly to looks better?

Comment: That will be easy if you're using `jquery`, but in pure js i don't know.

Comment: Ok I'll use jquery which functions is for effects ?

Comment: JQuery **[animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** function will do the work.

Comment: @Zakaria AcharkiCould you help with some code of animate function?